# Looping a function over columns with different number of rows in VBA

Tags: vba

I am dealing with a large dataset where every third column contains values for which I need to perform a function that takes value of 1 if it is positive than 0 and value of -1 if it is negative. Writing the function itself is no problem, but the dimensions of the data matrix are large and the columns are not of equal length. Thus I would need to be able to write a code that loops over the columns, performing the task, and saves the results in another matrix with equal number of colummns and rows of the same length. To be more concrete, an example of the dataset I am dealing with and what I want to achieve:

```
x1;x2;x3;x4
1;-1;2;4
-5;1;2;-1
1; ;2;1
3; ; ;-4
5; ; ; 
6; ; ;
```

And transfer this into:

```
y1;y2;y3;y4
1;-1;1;1
-1;1;1;-1
1; ;1;1
1; ; ;-1
1; ; ;
1; ; ;
```

x's and y's need to be on the same row.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
In reality, what I am dealing with is something that looks more like this:

```
Timestamp   Last    Trade Volume    Timestamp   Last    Trade Volume    Timestamp   Last    Trade Volume    Timestamp   Last    Trade Volume
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    3300    4.1.2016 13:34  7.82    100 4.1.2016 13:34  4.58    3000    4.1.2016 13:35  4.59    #N/A
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    600 4.1.2016 13:34  7.83    300 4.1.2016 13:34  4.58    5750    4.1.2016 13:34  4.61    1000
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    1000    4.1.2016 13:34  7.85    200 4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    300 4.1.2016 13:34  4.61    9500
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    800 4.1.2016 13:34  7.85    500 4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    2000    4.1.2016 13:34  4.6 2200
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    1200    4.1.2016 13:34  7.85    1700    4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    1000    4.1.2016 13:34  4.6 1200
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    400 4.1.2016 13:34  7.85    100 4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    950 4.1.2016 13:33  4.6 500
4.1.2016 13:34  3.12    600 4.1.2016 13:34  7.85    200 4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    100 4.1.2016 13:33  4.6 2000
4.1.2016 13:34  3.11    4500    4.1.2016 13:34  7.85    1800    4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    750 4.1.2016 13:33  4.61    7500
4.1.2016 13:34  3.11    300 4.1.2016 13:34  7.82    2000    4.1.2016 13:34  4.58    500 4.1.2016 13:33  4.59    1400
4.1.2016 13:34  3.11    3700    4.1.2016 13:34  7.83    1000    4.1.2016 13:34  4.59    2000    4.1.2016 13:33  4.59    11000
```

Except that the rows are not of equal length, I have 300+ columns and the longest rows are over 100,000+ long. I need to be able to run this thing over the Last columns only, I have a different code to be ran over the Volume column. I am completely fine with a solution that allows for me to paste a cell including the formula for a column of corresponding length, but pasting the code over the whole array is not doable because it will crash the whole excel, i.e. I need to be able to omit the cells that have no values form the loop.

Comment: What have you coded / tried thus far? Please add your VBA code to the question. I'd be especially interested to see the function which does not seem to pose a problem.

Comment: you said "every third column" but the examples you gave seem to act on every column. how's that?

Comment: Added an example of the actual file. Thanks for the clarifyin question.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't have the code in front of me, but I think I can still help.

What about xlLastCell? I mean, that might not be the most efficient, but that would be the easiest. Just get the row and column of xlLastCell, and for row=1 to lastrow, for col=1 to lastcol, if it is blank then next col/next row, if abs(cell.value)=cell.value then sheets(2).cells(row,col)=1, else it =-1. You mentioned every third column, I would then just use an if .row mod 3 = (1,2,0 depending on what you need) to decide if you should next col or do that column.
Now, this only works if by 'another matrix' you just mean another spreadsheet. If you mean a 2d array, you could find xlLastCell, and then redim matrix(lastrow,lastcol) as int, and put it all in the matrix instead of sheet2.
Or, if you mean something completely different, then I apologize, and I am not sure.

Comment: I see the edit you put in this morning. I am still not sure why running a loop 30+ million times would crash excel, but if you are having that problem, I suggest reformatting the data.

Comment: Not quite as easy as what I suggested, but still pretty easy. You could code something fancy if you wanted, but since we are only talking about 300-400 columns, it would be faster to just record a macro. Highlight columns D-F, cut, new sheet (or better a database table in something meant to hold data, even Access would work, but not my call), paste in A1, switch back to original sheet. Stop recording, add a hotkey, and just press the hotkey about a hundred times.